# How to see what APIs are called by Liferay?

Tags: java, api, logging, liferay

I am debugging a Vue application which is running on top of the Liferay.

I am trying to see a list of APIs which Liferay called durring some specific period.

Here is the problem that Vue does not call APIs directly. APIs are called by the Liferay and then Liferay generates virtual APIs and Vue calls those APIs which Liferay exposes.

Normally, for a simple Web application, I would simply go to Development Tools in a browser to see a list of APIs which are called. But since Liferay serves as a proxy here, all what I can see in Dev Tools are calls to those virtual APIs which Liferay exposes, not the actual APIs which Liferay calls.

Also, Liferay has some access log file where it logs all APIs that get called, but, unfortunately, it logs calls to virtual Liferay APIs which Vue makes, not real APIs that Liferay calls.

So, is it possible to see this list?

Sure, I can manually go through code and implement logging on all places in the code where real API is called, but I would like to know if there is some Liferay provided solution.

Comment: "a vue application" on top of Liferay is, by definition, custom code. Please provide a [mcve] and consider listing * expectations * observations * steps to reproduce * version numbers of software involved

Comment: Thank you for a reply. I have no idea how to make a reproducible example here. I am pretty new to Liferay and the project i am working on has thousands and thousands of files. Liferay I am using is Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.0.4 GA5 (Wilberforce / Build 7004 / October 23, 2017), if that means anything to anyone. By my understanding, there should be some config file somewhere where we can set up Liferay to log calls to all APIs which it makes. I was expecting that there is some universal solution of how to turn on API calls logging in Liferay, that is why I asked.

Comment: If there is not, then I will just go through all config files and try to find something. :)